# How to remove the power on $y$ in $y^2 = x^2 +152$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to be able to graph this function but first I need to remove the power on y. Do I just square root both sides and get the following?

> $$y=x+\sqrt{152}$$

Comment: it is $y=\sqrt{x^2+152}$

Comment: The square root of $x^2 + 152$ is _not_ $x + \sqrt{152}$. If only it were that easy. Number theory would be trivial.

Comment: Freshman's dream strikes again.

Comment: @janmarqz: $\pm$.

Comment: easiest way to graph is draw the line $y=\sqrt{x^2+152}$ then reflect this in the x axis as it should be y is plus-minus f(x)

Comment: You know you can graph functions without a calculator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you've fallen victim to the [Freshman's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream).

The best way to graph this function is actually $$y=\pm\sqrt{x^2+152}$$You  can't do anything more with it.

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k8nshcznrf) it is graphed

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't split a square root like

$\sqrt{a+b}\neq\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ since $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2=a+b+2\sqrt{ab}\neq\sqrt{a+b}^2=a+b$. So in general, in order to remove the power, we have to take the square root, hence $|y|=\sqrt{x^2+152}$ which can't be simplified unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The square root of $x^2 + 152$ is not $x + \sqrt 152$.  It is $\sqrt{x^2 + 152}$.  And that is only the positive square root.  $y$ could also be the negative square root.

Square rooting both sides gives you

$y^2 = x^2 + 152$

$y = \pm \sqrt {x^2 + 152}$.

It is *essential* to realize $\sqrt{a + b} \ne \sqrt a + \sqrt b$.  Just try a few values and you'll see that simply is not true.